# .jsx always in a React Project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Will you always have .jsx file extensions in a React app?  What if you're using Babel? Do you still need .jsx files or do you simple do react.createElement all over and babel transpiles it and no need for .jsx extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use jsx syntax, but you can still use react and without it.  It's optional, but I recommend using jsx.

You will probably want to use a tool like webpack or browserify which will package your transpiled client side code, but source maps can be used to debug the jsx.

Comment: if not using jsx, how would you use react?  Trying to find examples of using it vs. not

Comment: and when you say use it, do you end up having .jsx files or that you just use jsx syntax inside .js files?

Comment: The jsx files are 'compiled' to js

Comment: right but does everyone use .jsx files?   I saw a project that had no .jsx files...only .js files

Comment: ok I can compare here https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/5vjqabv3/ with https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/.  Seems to me doing without jsx is less of a black box, just use createElement plus I could mock elements in the same fashion with manual mocks if I wanted to it seems

Comment: plus if it's plain JS, debugging I'd assume is straight forward...just step into the react js!

Comment: yea I've concluded no jsx.  I'm gonna use Uber's r-dom https://github.com/uber/r-dom